# Provided column type matrix is unknown. Cannot proceed with parse due to invalid argument

Tags: r, h2o

I am trying to run H2o to Titanic dataset. I know there shouldn't be ordered factor and there is not:

```
> str(dataset)
'data.frame':   889 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Survived: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ Pclass  : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 3 1 3 1 3 3 1 3 3 2 ...
 $ Sex     : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 ...
 $ Age     : num [1:889, 1] -0.592 0.638 -0.285 0.408 0.408 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr "Age"
 $ Embarked: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 2 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 2 ...
 - attr(*, "na.action")= 'omit' Named int [1:2] 62 830
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "62" "830"
```

But there is still this mistake:

```
> dataset <- as.h2o(dataset)

ERROR: Unexpected HTTP Status code: 412 Precondition Failed (url = http://localhost:54321/3/Parse)

water.exceptions.H2OIllegalArgumentException
 [1] "water.exceptions.H2OIllegalArgumentException: Provided column type matrix is unknown.  Cannot proceed with parse due to invalid argument."
...
org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)"                             
[39] "    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:762)"                                                     
[40] "    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:680)"                                                      
[41] "    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)"                                                                                      

Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = page,  : 
  

ERROR MESSAGE:

Provided column type matrix is unknown.  Cannot proceed with parse due to invalid argument.
```

Could you help me how to fix this?

Comment: Your `age` column seems to be a matrix which is unusual. Try making it just a normal numeric vector `dataset$Age <- as.vector(dataset$Age)`. I'd also suggest tracking down the code that created the unusual data. When you import data into R, you normally wouldn't get such a structure.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Now everything runs. Thank you!